# How to view test results for in-progress tests in the release pipeline view?

Tags: automated-tests, azure-devops, coded-ui-tests, test-results

According to...:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=vsts

​...You should be able to view test results for in-progress (automated)tests during the test execution but my test results are not published until the whole test run is complete. What am i doing wrong here?

In my release definition i have the Visual Studio test task. The automated GUI tests is executed from the Azure DevOps testHub which trigger the release job, but as said, the test results will not update until all tests are completed. How can this be done?

[image]

Also, why are my tests shown as "Others" and not "Not executed"?

​(Im using the "Test run" option in the Visual studio test task for "Select tests using".)

[image]

Comment: What about the general unit tests? I mean not the automated GUI tests.

Comment: I dont know anything about our unit tests sorry. The developers know them better than me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you configured it wrong.

In docs it's said:
[image]

**So what needs to be done is on your test task you should switch on parallel run:**
[image]

But be careful with parallel running, it may require some work with your tests to make it possible.